# OpenVPN in crontab problems

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi, vpn, openvpn

I have this easy script for checking connection of specific interface with one condition.

If interface exists do nothing, if not dial VPN

```
#!/bin/bash
FOUND=`grep "tap0" /proc/net/dev`

if  [ -n "$FOUND" ] ; then
echo yes
else

openvpn /home/pi/vpn/data/bezpasaka.opvn > /home/pi/vpn/errors.txt
fi
```

When I execute that it is working.

I also needed to add in into crontab so

```
*/1 * * * * /home/pi/vpn/checkvpn.sh
```

It supposed to work, I tried different bash with mkdir only and it was working fine.

Cron execute checkvpn.sh (i can see that in processes using :

> ps ax | grep 'checkvpn.sh'

The problem I think is, that after cron execute checkvpn.sh it dials VPN and it gooooes all to the end until it cancelled whole connection because he can't hold the session probably. Atleast that what I though after checking errors.txt file

Have you any idea about any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
openvpn /home/pi/vpn/data/bezpasaka.opvn > /home/pi/vpn/errors.txt
```

where does `openvpn` located? when the cron get executed it does not normally loads `PATH` variables and hence does not know how to execute `openvpn`. You need to give full path of `openvpn` like `/usr/bin/openvpn` in order for this to work.

also please check whether `openvpn` requires `tty` or not

Comment: _openvpn /home/pi/vpn/data/bezpasaka.opvn > /home/pi/vpn/errors.txt_ this line is bash things already isn't it?But Imma try that, after i find where is that location

Comment: you can check its location by using `whereis openvpn`